# Правильное кэширование YII. Часть 1

Tags: activerecord, php, yii, кэширование

Привет всем!

Уже некоторое время разрабатываю на yii проектик, точнее, модуль одного большого проектика. Использую ActiveRecord. Есть у нас в базе одна таблица, которая связана с несколькими другими таблицами, там на одну запись связей примерно 20-30, в итоге, при выводе в браузер 100 объектов, в БД совершается около 500 запросов, соответственно, страница грузится от секунды - до трех. Это не хорошо, и к счастью, нам дали время на допиливание и доведение до ума наших проектов.Собственно, решил исправить тормознутость своей системы, и заняться кэшированием. Ради интереса включил кэширование в файлы, скорость работы системы увеличилась, пользователи это заметили. Причем, кэшируются сейчас только сами объекты, связи к ним пока еще не кэшируются.

В общем, почитал по интернетам, нагуглил умное слово memcached, озадачил нашего одмина, чтоб ставил сие чудо над евелоперскую машину,а сам начал изучать, как делать правильное кэширование объектов ActiveRecord в Yii. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Может существуют какие-то техники кэширование AR? В общем, за любые ссылки, или ответы буду благодарен)

Answer (score 1):

Не буду постить все ссылки, только одну [начальную](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/caching.overview). Вам нужно задуматься над тем что бы пересмотреть архитектуру приложения, т.к. 20-30 связей это, на мой взгляд, слишком уж. Обязательно используйте [ленивую загрузку](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr).
Кэшировать нужно не всю страницу, а полученные данные из БД (не забывать разделять их на данные для авторизованного или конкретного пользователя, данные для гостя и прочие...), блоки страниц (опять же разделение!).

И совет, не используйте в своей речи уменьшительно ласкательные слова, иначе к вам серьезно относиться не будут. Проект будь он маленьким или большим он всегда будет проектом!

Comment: Спасибо, но увы, архитектуру приложения пересматривать, и тем более, переделывать, никто не будет, т.к. в то, что уже сейчас есть вложено более года разработки, и 7-ми значная сумма денег

Comment: Хочу еще добавить, что memcache способен хранить в одной ячейке 1 мегабайт данных, так что имейте ввиду.

Comment: Спасибо, ценный совет)

Буду искать информацию о том, Как можно переопределить класс ActiveRecord таким образом, чтобы при вызове любой модели, унаследованной от этого класса, информация сначала искалась в кэше)